# Testing with a twisted deferred

Tags: python, twisted, trial

I have been struggling to wrap my head around testing twisted code with deferred's and deferred's in general.

I have a simple test that really should fail, I think.

From my undertstanding in Twisted's test tool Trial, I should be able to return a deferred and when it is finished the test will finish.

Here is my tidbit of code, maybe someone can help.

```
import unittest, time

from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

def test_simple_deferred(self):

    print "\nStarting Test"

    my_deferred = defer.Deferred()

    def print_time():
      print time.time()
      self.assertTrue(False)

    my_deferred.addCallback(print_time)

    reactor.callLater(3, my_deferred.callback)

    print time.time()

    return my_deferred
```

Thanks in advance, I have looked at a lot of examples, but I think I have gotten to the point that I have been looking at this for far too long.

Comment: Have you read https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/trial.html ?

Comment: Of course, unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out exactly what is wrong with my code.  Returning a deferred that is still active to should force the test to wait until it is not longer active.  The examples are much more complicated than my simple no brainer, but I know I am doing something dumb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems.

Firstly, to get the special deferred handling, your test case needs to inherit from `twisted.trial.unittest.TestCase`, not the python standard library version.

Lastly, you are not calling `reactor.callLater` properly, or rather, you aren't giving it the right arguments for `Deferred.callback()`;  you need to give the deferred a *value*.  If you don't care what it is, give it a `None`.  Likewise, the callback needs to *take* that argument; you can safely ignore it.

```
from twisted.trial import unittest
#^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
import time

from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_simple_deferred(self):

        print "\nStarting Test"

        my_deferred = defer.Deferred()

        def print_time(dont_care):
        #              ^^^^^^^^^
            print time.time()
            self.assertTrue(False)

        my_deferred.addCallback(print_time)

        reactor.callLater(3, my_deferred.callback, None)
        #                                        ^^^^^^    
        print time.time()

        return my_deferred
```

Comment: Wow, I spent way to long looking at that.  I had the callLater call correct when I first wrote it but I tweaked so many different things after I got stuck.  Thanks for the help ...